# Get first row that is null in Oracle DB table

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the following table

| rownum | ID | date | owner |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 09/01/2022 | null |
| 2 | 1 | 09/02/2022 | null |
| 3 | 1 | 09/03/2022 | Joe |
| 4 | 1 | 09/04/2022 | null |
| 5 | 1 | 09/05/2022 | Jack |
| 6 | 2 | 09/01/2022 | null |
| 7 | 2 | 09/02/2022 | John |
| 8 | 2 | 09/02/2022 | John |
| 9 | 2 | 09/02/2022 | John |

For every ID, I want to select the first occurrence of null that eventually results in a non-null value. So rows 1, 4, and 6.

(Note that rownum is not a column; I just added it here for illustration only)

Query output:

| ID | date | owner |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 09/01/2022 | null |
| 1 | 09/04/2022 | null |
| 2 | 09/01/2022 | null |

What is the best way to go about it on an Oracle 11g DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can phrase this as a gaps and islands problem, with each island being a contiguous group of `NULL` owner records.  From each island, we can return the earliest date.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY "date") rn1,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, owner ORDER BY "date") rn2
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT ID, MIN("date") AS "date", NULL AS owner
FROM cte
WHERE owner IS NULL
GROUP BY ID, rn1 - rn2
ORDER BY ID, "date";
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo